# Racket, brag: match on the val of a token

Tags: parsing, racket

Is it possible in a parser written in `#lang brag`, to match on the value of a token rather than the type?
For example I have a token type `'WORD`, which matches any cluster of word characters. So a token could be `(token 'WORD "some_word")`. The grammar of my DSL has a rule which requires the specific word "start" at some place so it should accept `(token 'WORD "start")` in that place. However I get this error `;parser-non-terminals: start used as both token and non-terminal`. (without using `start` as a non-terminal.) Here is my `brag` code in any case:

```
#lang brag
program : sexpr* startt* layout
sexpr   : SEXPR

startt   : "start" WORD "[" WORD* "=>" sexpr "]"

layout  : elem*
elem    : info | text | sexpr
info    : "{" text "}"
text    : WORD*


;parser-non-terminals: start used as both token and non-terminal
```

Comment: Please paste the code into your question instead of linking externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#racket` @ freenode, figured out that matching literals like "start", "error" and "atok" yields an error, which is probably a bug in brag or yacc. Since I'm also having some other difficulties I will try another parser generator. Otherwise, I would probably match a general 'WORD non-terminal and assert that it equals "start" in the expander.